# fontspec package not compatible with inline preview TeXStudio

Tags: fontspec, texstudio

I've installed MiKTeX 2.9 and TeXStudio 2.4. I found suggestions on the web to change the default compiler to XeLaTeX, to provide accentuated  words (I am portuguese!), to handle any type of images (pdf, eps, jpg, etc) and also to use system fonts. This seemed very interesting, as I usually use pdfLaTeX.
However, I am dealing with some problems that I would like to solve.

First, I found that even with XeLaTeX we need to provide the `fontspec` package such as to have accentuated words (well, I could use pdfLaTeX and `fontenc` package with the same results). Is that right? If I build a file written in portuguese with XeLaTeX and without `fontspec` I get no accents.

Second, when I use `fontspec` package, the Inline preview of TeXStudio does not work. Is there any known bug or incompatibility of `fontspec` with inline preview?

So the problem is: Compiling with XeLaTeX and `fontspec` provides me with accents but no inline preview. Compiling with XeLaTeX without `fontspec` provides me inline preview and no accents!

What am I missing?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) What does “no inline preview” mean (error/crash, no preview window at all, no content)?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! XeLaTeX without `fontspec` is essentially like LaTeX without `inputenc`, so you have to specify accents "the old way". So `fontspec` is highly recommended (it gives also easy access to all system fonts in OpenType or TrueType format). It's not clear what you mean with inline preview.

Comment: By "no accents" I mean no character at all.

By inline preview I mean the functionality of Texstudio where you can compile pieces of code by selecting it and using Preview Selection/Parenthesis of menu Idefix. The result appears directly in the Editor.

Comment: I tried to preview in the Editor a formula so I selected it and used Alt + P. I got

Process started: latex.exe -interaction=nonstopmode -ini "&latex hNl3232 \dump"
Process exited with error(s)
Process started: latex.exe -src -interaction=nonstopmode "fl3232".tex
Process exited with error(s)
Process started: dvips.exe -E -o "fl3232".ps "fl3232".dvi
Process exited with error(s)
Process started: mgs.exe -q -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=png16m -dEPSCrop -sOutputFile="C:\Users\Luis\AppData\Local\Temp\.\fl32321.png" "C:\Users\Luis\AppData\Local\Temp\.\fl3232.ps"
Process exited with error(s)

Comment: This uses LaTeX which compiles a `.dvi` file that is than converted to a `.png` image. This image is shown to you. Afaik there is no possibility LaTeX could handle XeLaTeX stuff. (And I couldn't find a way to change the command that is called internally. Check the “Messages” tab to follow the internals.)

Comment: So it seems that there is no solution. If I want to use inline preview I should not use xelatex.

Comment: @Luis As Qrrbrbirlbel says, that "small preview" can't work with XeLaTeX, since `dvipng` (which is used to produce the image) currently doesn't understand the special output format of XeTeX (which is called XDV and is a variant of DVI with more features). There might be a way to use it also for XeLaTeX, but this is a topic to be discussed with the developers of TeXStudio.